# Alternative to OpenOffice for converting PowerPoint to PDF

Tags: pdf, export, powerpoint, file-conversion, pyuno

I'm currently using OpenOffice API (pyuno) to convert PowerPoint to PDF. However, the conversions end up looking not very good. I'm wondering if there is a conversion utility that has better output than OpenOffice.

Comment: You could try LibreOffice.  Based on the same core, but has been evolving separately for enough time that it's probably worth trying.

Comment: Sounds like LibreOffice uses the same PyUNO as OpenOffice, so I'm guessing the resulting conversion would be the same.

Comment: Why not use Powerpoint directly?

Comment: Files are uploaded to a Linux server and then processed on the backend by the server. By "OpenOffice" I meant the OpenOffice converter.

Comment: I'd suggest to convert slides to images first.